# Access private folder in iOS

Tags: ios, swift3, nsurl

I have some files in which they after being downloaded they are stored in the following folder/path

`/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5527BBC6-651F-4E29-A3ED-E31FABCE958F/Documents/7A7D61AE-B368-4999-8A59-C88AD5AA07CD.pdf`

inside the `/private/` folder.

How can I access this file? no matter what I cannot access them, am I missing some permission in the app?

How can I create an URL to access files at that `/private/` path?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An app cannot access files not on its own container - app is in a sandbox.

Check out this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) for More information

Specifically:

> An app is generally prohibited from accessing or creating files
>   outside its container directories. One exception to this rule is when
>   an app uses public system interfaces to access things such as the
>   user’s contacts or music.